# OpenIddict ClockSkew Configuration Not Working in Blazor Application(WASM)

Tags: blazor, openid, webassembly, abp, openiddict

I'm working on a *abp* project where I need to handle time incompatibility for users whose systems might have incorrect time settings. I've attempted to address this by configuring the `ClockSkew` in my *AuthServer* module as shown below:

```
 public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    PreConfigure<OpenIddictBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddValidation(options =>
        {
            options.AddAudiences("X");
            options.UseLocalServer();
            options.UseAspNetCore();
            options.Configure(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0);
            });
        });
    });
    
    PreConfigure<OpenIddictServerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetAuthorizationCodeLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        builder.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        builder.SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        builder.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
    });

}
```

Users are able to log in to the *AuthServer* app successfully. However, when they are redirected to the Blazor WASM app, the following error message is displayed: "There was an error trying to log you in". This suggests that the `ClockSkew` setting is not working as expected.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the `TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew` was added in OpenIddict 5.0. That said, it only affects validation performed by the OpenIddict client, server or validation stacks.

If you want to change the rules of the validation routine performed by the Blazor WASM OIDC client, you'll need to get your hands dirty: a `ClockSkew` option exists in `oidc-client-js` (the library used under the hood by Blazor), but it's not very easy to set it. See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36028 for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the accepted clock skew in the clients or API's that accepts tokens, as this is checked during token validation.

You can set that, for example, like this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ...
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    };
});
```

Comment: I cannot find this configuration in the Blazor WebAssembly project anywhere

Comment: see https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazo/general/how-do-i-implement-blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect  , is an option to AddOpenIdConnect, under TokenValidationParameters   ? But I haven't used Blazor myself, but would assume it would be pretty much the same.

Comment: your link is for Blazor Server app